On binary constraints defined by vanishing of bivariate polynomials modulo $n$
In an answer here
Dima Pasechnik showed that constraints of the form $x_i x_j + a_{ij}x_i + b_{ij}x_j + c_{ij}$ are efficiently solvable modulo $2$ using Groebner basis.
In comments he suggested that other fields would work too.
In short, we are looking for other islands of tractability in larger
characteristic and larger degree.
In terms of constraint satisfaction, we are working with special
case of binary constraint over alphabet of size greater than two,
which in general is NP-complete, we believe.
Let $n$ be positive integer and $f_i(x_i,x_j)$ bivariate polynomials
with integer coefficients. Let $D=\max\deg{f_i}$.
Given $n$ and $m$ variables and $f_1,f_2,...,f_k$, we are interested in solving
$f_i=0$ modulo $n$,
having the phreedom to chose $n$ prime.

Q1 For which choices of $D,n$ (answer may depend on the primality
of $n$) solving the system $f_i=0$ is efficient?

According to our experiments with random instances, $D>2,n>2$ is
slow as measured by wall clock time.

Q2 Assume that all $f_i$ are of the form
$f_i(x,y)=(a_{i,1} x + a_{i,2} y +a_{i,3})\cdot(b_{j,1} x + b_{j,2} y + b_{j,3})$

For which choices of $D,n$ solving $f_i=0$ is efficient?
According to our limited experiments, it is efficient for all $n$,
including composites.

Q3 Is the case $n=3,D=2$ clear? (Quadratic polynomials modulo $3$)


For prime $n$ the poynomial system in Q2 is uquivalent to the union of $2^k$ systems of linear equations.

@MaxAlekseyev Thanks. I fixed minor typo. The linked question solved Q2 for $n=2$.

@MaxAlekseyev According to my test in sage, for k=150,n=7 the groebner basis was computed fast and it is far from 2^150 linear equations.
