Non-linear recurrence for rational sequences with generating function with radicals?
Let $a(n)$ be a sequence of rational numbers with generating
function $F(x)$.
Assume $F(x)$ is composition of rational functions and radicals
(roots).
Is the following conjecture true:

Conjecture 1: $a(n)=G(a(n-1),a(n-2),...,a(n-d_1))/H(a(n-1),...,a(n-d_2))$
for polynomials $G$,$H$ with rational coefficients .

Let $F(x)=\frac{1}{{(1+x)}^{\frac12}}$.
$a(n)$ starts $-1/2, 3/8, -5/16, 35/128, -63/256$

Q2 Do we have $a(n)=\frac{(-a(n-2)a(n-1) - \frac12 a(n-1)^2)}{(\frac32 a(n-2) + a(n-1))}$
for all $n$?

According to our tests with sage and pari/gp, not all $F(x)$
result in rational $a(n)$.
sage code is available online.
Wolfram Alpha gives closed form recurrence with polynomial
coefficients and algebraic initial values for
series 1/(1+x+x^2)^(1/3)here
series 1/(1+x+x^2)^(1/4)here

In your example, there is a simple expression for $a(n)$ in terms of binomial coefficients. How hard can it be to answer Q2?

I guess $F(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$ would be an example where the coefficients involve $\sqrt2$ and are not rational. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286718/taylor-expansion-for-sqrtx2

@GerryMyerson For $F(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$ the sequence $a(n)$ is not rational. This case is described in the original question and it asks for cases when $a(n)$ is rational.

All I see in the original question is "According to our tests ... not all $F(x)$ result in rational $a(n)$." So, I thought some user might like to see an explicit example, to supplement your unsupported assertion.

@GerryMyerson In addition to that the title has rational and the first sentence has rational in bold.

Wolfram Alpha gives partial results

I can read, joro, and I still don't see where you gave any example where the $a(n)$ are not rational, and I still think that my comment had value in giving an explicit example where you failed to do so.

A composition $F(x)=\sum a(n)x^n\in\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ of rational
functions with radicals is algebraic. The coefficients $a(n)$ of an
algebraic power series are P-recursive, meaning that there are
polynomials $P_0(n),\dots, P_d(n)$ for which
$$ P_d(n)a(n+d)+P_{d-1}(n)a(n+d-1)+\cdots+P_0(n)a(n) =0,\ \ n\geq 0. $$
Since $a(n)\in\mathbb{Q}$ we also have
$P_i(n)\in\mathbb{Q}[n]$. References include my paper here
(Theorem 2.1) and the book D-Finite
Functions by Manuel Kauers. (Kauers uses the term "D-finite"
rather than "P-recursive.")
Addendum. As pointed out by joro, my answer above did not answer
the question. Here is another attempt. From my answer above, there
are polynomials $P_i(n)$ for which
$$ Q(n):=P_d(n)a(n+d)+P_{d-1}(n)a(n+d-1)+\cdots+P_0(n)a(n) =0. $$
Substituting $n+1$ for $n$, we get
$$ R(n):=
  P_d(n+1)a(n+d+1)+P_{d-1}(n+1)a(n+d)+\cdots+P_0(n+1)a(n+1)=0. $$
Regard $Q(n)$ and $R(n)$ as polynomials in $n$ whose coefficients are polynomials (or even linear forms) in the $P_i(n+k)$'s. Then the equation
$$ \mathrm{Resultant}(Q(n),R(n))=0 $$
gives the desired equation with constant coefficients. The only snag
is that the resultant might be 0. I believe this can be avoided by
taking $d$ minimal. This argument is completely analogous to the
solution to Exercise 6.63(d) in Enumerative Combinatorics, vol. 2,second edition.
Example. Let $a(n)=n!$, $A=f(n)$, $B=f(n+1)$, $C=f(n+2)$,
$Q(n)=B-(n+1)A$, $R(n)=C-(n+2)B$. Then
$$ \mathrm{Resultant}(Q(n),R(n))=AB-AC+B^2, $$
so $n!(n+1)!-n!(n+2)!+(n+1)!^2=0$.

Many thanks. The weak conjecture from the following question would eliminate $n$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476226/conjectured-somos-like-closed-form-of-recurrences-with-polynomial-coefficients?rq=1

@joro: what do you mean by "eliminate $n$"?

I mean: the linked question conjectures that if integer sequence $f(n)$ satisfy recurrence with polynomial in $n$ coefficients, then it satisfies $f(n)=G(f(n-1),f(n-2),...,f(n-d_1)/H(f(n-1),...,f(n-d_2))$ for polynomials with integer coefficients $G,H$.

This is a very interesting result, but it doesn't answer the question, since the question asks about constant coefficients.

I think your current resultant claim is incomplete. In addition to non-zero resultant, you need it linear in the leading variable, so you can express it as $G/H$. The paper in the linked question calls this linearity "luck". Counterexample to your current revision is resultant of the form $A^2+B^2-C^2$.

To answer Q2, it's enough to note that $a(n)=\frac{1-2n}{2n}a(n-1)$, implying that
$$\frac{(-a(n-2)a(n-1) - \frac12 a(n-1)^2)}{(\frac32 a(n-2) + a(n-1))}=\frac{(-1-\tfrac{3-2n}{4(n-1)})a(n-2)a(n-1)}{(\tfrac32 +\tfrac{3-2n}{2(n-1)})a(n-2)}=\frac{1-2n}{2n}a(n-1)=a(n).$$

Thanks. Do you have intuition about the general case? Wolfram Alpha gives partial results
